# how to delete all woocommerce product_tag from phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, woocommerce, phpmyadmin, tags, product

i have many thousand product_tag and useless for seo. How delete all woocommerce product tag from phpmyadmin?,
because if i delete just from dashboard very long time.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using part of the answer from this source:

[https://gist.github.com/mikaelz/9f98dcf9664c51e88900](http://Remove%20all%20WooCommerce%20product%20categories%20and%20tags)

```
DELETE a,c FROM wp_terms AS a 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS c ON a.term_id = c.term_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS b ON b.term_taxonomy_id = c.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE c.taxonomy = 'product_tag';
```

Please backup first as I cannot verify if this code is correct.